# Fiber CORS Middleware returning null Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Value

Tags: go, cors

I'm using the Go Fibre Web Framework and its complementary CORS Middleware component to implement my RESTful API. I configure CORS as specified in the official documentation however, rather oddly, when I then go on to call the API from cURL or Postman the: "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" Header **is** present in response but its value is: **null** and thus requests from **any** host appear to be being accepted.

Here is my setup as per the current documentation (which you may find [here](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/middleware/cors)):

```
//instantiate sever and store to local
apiServer = fiber.New()

//Setup CORS for a specific endpoint.
apiServer.Use("/api/v1/authentications/manage/login", cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     "http://[my-domain].com",
    AllowCredentials: true,
}))
```

Now there are no immediate or obvious errors and I'm able to successfully compile the application. However, when the resulting application is deployed and I use cURL to make a request to the endpoint and dump the resulting response headers I see the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Mon, 07 Jun 2021 11:28:31 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 130
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Origin
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Please note: the 401 Response is being returned as **expected** since (as per above) this is an Authentication endpoint and I omitted authentication credentials from the request. However, even when the correct credentials **ARE** provided a 200 OK Response is returned to ***any*** client that calls the endpoint. Now I could, of course, manually append the requisite headers to the response myself, but I really would rather utilise the CORS Middleware as it much cleaner than the manual approach.

Comment: Could you please share the request headers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Header is present in response but its value is: null and thus requests from any host appear to be being accepted.

That is not how it works. The header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should either contain the origin for the specific client making the request, or the wildcard `*`, in order to be accepted by the browser. If the origin header does not satisfy the origins you allowed, the response header will be an empty string as [you can see in the source code](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/master/middleware/cors/cors.go#L112).

Comment: Your are correct based on the source code at least. Thanks Riwen. I've not actually tested in an real browser, as mentioned, I'm using both Postman and cURL to test the end points, which both just seem to ignore the header. Maybe need to look into how I might simulate the full CORS request-response cycle in Postman (i.e including pre-flights,etc).

Comment: Note that some origins do serialise to `null`. However, allowing `null` is very insecure and should never be done.